# What is synchronization in asp.net exactly?

Tags: asp.net, synchronization

Hello how to synchronize asp.net page . means how can we maintain synchronization in asp.net while loading pages/ page ?

Comment: What are you trying to keep in synchronization with? Can you explain more about what you mean?

Comment: I mean to say how can we synchronize asp.net page while processing the request among various user accessing same page with same server instance

Comment: Do you meaning ajax ? it is basically asynchronous web pages. do you mean that exactly ?

Comment: are you talking about showing fresh data in your page after another user has updated it from their instance of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean :

```
lock(someVariable)
{
    ///Some code
    //Some read operations
    //Some write operations

}
```

This is to ensure that two threads accessing the code inside the braces, can only access the code one at a time.

Since the code contains read and write operations, if two threads were accessing the code at the same time, you could get inconsistent states for your data (just as an example). Thus, without the lock, the above code would not have been "Thead safe".

There are many such cases where thread safety might be required and the lock keyword addresses these cases.